# How can I save status of pressed button?

Tags: swift3, uibutton, ios11, swift4

I have tried many codes but doesn’t work. I want to save status of pressed button.

I have two DL radio buttons, I am using it for change between two languages first button for English language and second button for Arabic languages. I am using DLRadioButton framework, [this framework I am using it](https://github.com/DavydLiu/DLRadioButton/blob/master/README.md).

I want when I open the viewcontroller the English language button the indicator of button is pressed and indicator terns to black and when I change to Arabic I want to save the status of button when I close the app  and open it the indicator steels pressed, I have tried to use, user-default but didn’t work, this code for example .

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "issaved")
    UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "issaveded")
}

@IBAction func circularbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.tag == 0 ||  sender.isSelected == !sender.isSelected {
        let use = UserDefaults.standard
        use.set(  sender.isSelected, forKey: "issaved")
        use.synchronize()
    } else if sender.tag == 1 || sender.isSelected == sender.isSelected {
        let usee = UserDefaults.standard
        usee.set(  sender.isSelected, forKey: "issaveded")
        usee.synchronize()
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code you have tried.  For example you save you have tried to use user-defaults but how did you try that.

Comment: If the button is pressed then save the button state as true. If it's not pressed then change the state of the button to false

Comment: I have added my code @UpholderOfTruth

Comment: There you go @Sekiz you add the code and someone answers the question.  Always best to put the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Both lines to read the values from `UserDefaults` do nothing because you are not using the result.

- Create two outlets for the buttons and connect them in Interface Builder

  ```
  @IBOutlet weak var button1 : UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var button2 : UIButton!
  ```
- In `viewDidLoad` assign the values from `UserDefaults` to the buttons.

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      button1.isSelected = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "issaved")
      button2.isSelected = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "issaveded")
  }
  ```